# C fscanf reading the same line twice?

Tags: c, file

So my assignment is to create an assembler in C. So I have most of it working but the first part is to scan through the assembly file and look for labels and assign the correct 'program counter' location for each label. Everything works great unless there is a label at the bottom with a blank line below it and a .end directive after it. I tried printing every line to see what it is reading and it seems that it is reading the last label twice and thus it is incrementing my program counter twice for the same label and it is incorrect for just that label and I can't seem to figure out what the issue is. Any help is appreciated. At this point in time I haven't added in any logic to each command besides to increment the lc because that's all I need to do to complete this part atm.

```c
int firstPass(FILE *infile, int labels[], int lc)
{
    char line[LINE_SIZE] = {};
    int lineCount = 0;
    int done = 0;
    int endFound = -1;
    char c;
    rewind(infile);
    while (fscanf(infile, "%[^\n]", line) != EOF && lineCount < LIMIT && !done)
    {
        lineCount++;
        fscanf(infile, "%c", &c);
        removeSpaces(line);
        toUpperCase(line);
        if (line[0] != 0 && line[0] != ';')
        {
            if (!strncmp(line, ".END", 4))
            {
                done = 1;
                endFound = 0;
            }
            else if(!strncmp(line, "LDR", 3))
            {   
                lc++;
            }
            else if(!strncmp(line, "LD", 2))
            {
                lc++;
            }
            else if(!strncmp(line, "ADD", 3))
            {
                lc++;
            }
            else if(!strncmp(line, "AND", 3))
            {
                lc++;
            }
            else if(!strncmp(line, "NOT", 3))
            {
                lc++;
            }
            else if(!strncmp(line, "STR", 3))
            {
                lc++;
            }
            else if(!strncmp(line, "ST", 2))
            {
                lc++;
            }
            else if(!strncmp(line, "BR", 2))
            {
                lc++;
            }
            else if(!strncmp(line, "TRAP", 4))
            {
                lc++;
            }
            else if (line[0] == 'L' && line[1] >= '0' && line[1] <= '9')
            {
                if (line[2] == '.')
                {
                    labels[line[1] - '0'] = lc;
                    lc++;
                }
                else
                {
                    labels[line[1] - '0'] = lc;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    if (endFound == -1)
    {
        printf("ERROR 4: Missing end directive.\n");
    }
    return endFound;
}
```

Here is the test file I am using.

```
;Test file for assembly

;This is a comment

.orig x3000
    ADD R1, R2, R3
    add R0, R3, #10

    and R1, R1, R2
    AND R0, R3, #-10
L0          
    BR L1
    BRN L0
    BRZ L1
    BRP L0
    BRNZ L1
    BRNP L0
    BRZP L1
    BRNZP L0
    LD R1, L2
    LDR R1, R2, #-5
    L1          
    NOT R3, R4      
    ST R5, L2
    STR R6, R1, #-5 
    TRAP x20
    TRAP x21
    TRAP x22
    TRAP x23
    TRAP x24
    TRAP x25
    L2  .FILL   0   
L3  .FILL   0   
L4  .FILL   0

.END
```

Whenever I print the labels to the consoles it prints

```
L0

L1

L2 .FILL 0
L3 .FILL 0
L4 .FILL 0
L4 .FILL 0
```

I can't seem to figure out why it appears to be reading L4 twice.

Comment: It's not reading the line twice. It's just  not converting anything that matches the specifier `[^\n]`. The return value will be 0 for that line.  Why don't you just use `fgets`, which is actually meant to do what you're trying to coax `scanf` to accomplish?

Comment: You have `while (fscanf(infile, "%[^\n]", line) != EOF && lineCount < LIMIT && !done)`; you need to know what `fscanf()` returns, so you need `int rc; while ((rc = fscanf(infile, "%[^\n]", line)) != EOF && lineCount < LIMIT && !done)` so that you can test whether you got any data (`rc == 1`) or not (`rc == 0`) inside the loop.  If you didn't get anything, you need to continue without processing.  It's tough when you're given a defective skeleton code to work with.

Comment: @Gene just because I was given this contruct by my professor and told not to change it :/

Comment: @DylanBeech Well, you can let your professor know he or she is using the wrong idiom for line input. Maybe that's worth a few points :-)  In addition to the problem you've run into, you'd never use this in production code because it's a buffer overflow attack waiting to happen.

Answer (score 4):

`fscanf` primarily returns the number of items successfully read in. If you have an empty line (i.e. just a new line), then `fscanf(infile, "%[^\n]", line)` will not read in anything into `line`, and `line` remains unchanged (i.e. has the value of the previous "line" in the file).

To overcome this, check the return value of `fscanf` more accurately:

```
int fscanfResult;
while ((fscanfResult=fscanf(infile, "%[^\n]", line) != EOF && ...) {
   if (fscanfResult == 0) {
      fgets(line,infile);  // take the new line out of the buffer.
      continue;
   }
   ...
```

Generally, I'd tend to read in complete lines using `fgets` and parse it afterwards. `fscanf` has a lot of pitfalls when using it to scan line-based inputs.

If you have to keep the `while`-part as is, then another way to detect empty lines is to reset the buffer before the next `fscanf`:

```
while (fscanf(infile, "%[^\n]", line) != EOF && lineCount < LIMIT && !done) {
  if (!line[0]) { // nothing read in?
      fgets(line,infile);  // take the new line out of the buffer.
      continue;
  }

  ....
  // all your logic goes here
  ....
  line[0] = '\0'; // clear the buffer; if fscanf then does not read in anything, line remains empty.
}
```

Comment: Yeah I had an issue in another post as well and some people were telling me about fgets and such as well but unfortunately this while statement was given to me by my teacher and he asked us not to change it otherwise his tests would give us a 0 but I'll have to see how much I can change and get away with to still pass the tests. Thank you very much.

Comment: @DylanBeech: With luck, your prof's test code won't submit an empty line at the start (but you're right to worry about that case). And maybe he won't check for the exact spelling of the `while` loop, but if I was the prof, then (a) I wouldn't use this framework, but (b) supposing I was adamant about it, then I'd check the code for an exact match and reject changed code. So, I'd not bet on being able to get away with changing it. You might have to use `line[0] = '\0';` just before the end of the loop to spot when you get no input. When the scan fails to read, it doesn't assign to any variables.